# make owl carousel items alignment to center

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel in which images are taken through PHP, so that i can't predict the number of items in that and i am using carousel which contains 10 items(items:10). some times the returned PHP output will contain lesser images (1,2,3..) at that time the image is aligned to left but i wanted it to be in the center. my code will be as follows

html

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
 <div><img src="Images/image1.png class="br" ></div>
 <div><img src="Images/image1.png class="br" ></div>
</div>
```

Actual code is a php returned output,here i am writing its html only
JQuery

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
// Most important owl features
items : 10,
itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
itemsDesktopSmall : [980,3],
itemsTablet: [768,2],
itemsTabletSmall: false,
itemsMobile : [479,1],
singleItem : false,

//Basic Speeds
slideSpeed : 200,
paginationSpeed : 800,
rewindSpeed : 1000,

//Pagination
pagination : true,
paginationNumbers: false,

// Responsive 
responsive: true,
responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
responsiveBaseWidth: window,

// CSS Styles
baseClass : "owl-carousel",
theme : "owl-theme",

//Lazy load
lazyLoad : false,
lazyFollow : true,

//Auto height
autoHeight : false,
autoWidth : true,
loop:true,
center:true,

//JSON 
jsonPath : false, 
jsonSuccess : false,

//Mouse Events
mouseDrag : true,
touchDrag : true,

stagePadding: 50,
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
//Transitions
transitionStyle : false,

// Other
addClassActive : false,

//Callbacks
beforeInit: false, 
afterInit: false, 
beforeMove: false, 
afterMove: false,
afterAction: false,
startDragging : false
})
```

CSS

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 height: 0;
}
/* display none until init */
.owl-carousel{
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{
 -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item{
 float: left;
}
.owl-controls .owl-page,.owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* fix */
.owl-carousel  .owl-wrapper,.owl-carousel  .owl-item{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Could you put this into a JSFiddle or similar? It would help others to debug the problem for you.
As an aside this might help you: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to:

1. Get the count of items in php.
2. Print the result in html with your images.
3. Assign the count to JavaScript variable. (check if count is > 10 then asisgn 10)
4. Assign the owlCarousel function to `owl-example` id and pass the count variable to `items` in owlCarousel object.

Hope this may help you.